# Spring Colud config server not loading configuration from AWS s3 bucket

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am working on a spring boot micro-service architecture.Based on the architecture,we created a spring cloud config server.Configurations are placed in an AWS s3 bucket.The config Server will deployed in a EBS(Elastic bean stock).
Now the config server not loading the properties file.Spring cloud config server **properties .yml** given below

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
    
  profiles:
    active: awss3
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        awss3:
          bucket: micorservice-config-repo
          region: us-east-1
          order: 1
     
server:
  port: 8888
```

This configuration is based on the spring doc:-
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_aws_s3_backend

Application start log from console

```
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.7.0)[0;39m

[2m2022-06-17 15:24:35.342[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.n.c.ConfigserverApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting ConfigserverApplication using Java 1.8.0_251 on INLC4GQZH3 with PID 20496 (C:\Users\microservice\configserver\target\classes started by armohan2101 in C:\Users\microservice\configserver)
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:35.344[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.n.c.ConfigserverApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The following 1 profile is active: "awss3"
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:35.911[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m BeanFactory id=3a070de4-e11d-31ec-83f0-5d6f08cf7aa6
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:36.091[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:36.097[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:36.097[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:36.203[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:36.203[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 831 ms
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:37.366[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mDiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Eureka HTTP Client uses RestTemplate.
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.079[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36miguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.115[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.150[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.153[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.167[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Disable delta property : false
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.167[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Single vip registry refresh property : null
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.167[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Force full registry fetch : false
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.167[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application is null : false
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.167[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Registered Applications size is zero : true
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.167[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application version is -1: true
[2m2022-06-17 15:24:39.167[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
```

**Browser through accessing the configuration**
Url:-http://localhost:8888/application/microservice-one/

**response**

```
{"name":"application","profiles":["microservice-one-awss3"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

I have modified the properties file name as well.But not working.
Would you able to help me this issue.

Waiting for a replay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution already? I'm stuck with the same//

Comment: @Lucasz Sorry to say that i couldn't find any solution.am using gitlab  instead of s3.its working fine for me

Comment: Yes, I think it will be a problem with the dependencies. But did not have time to look further into.
If I know I will update you here.